# Error occurred during initialization of VM from a remote debian VM

Tags: java, user-interface, debian, virtual-machine

I know my question is related to some others, but the answers I found don't work for me. That's my problem: I have to run a JAVA script on a remote debian VM (from bash). When I run the program I get this:

```
 Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.processmining.framework.util.ProMClassLoader
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1469)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1436)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.processmining.framework.util.ProMClassLoader
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at java.lang.SystemClassLoaderAction.run(ClassLoader.java:2209)
    at java.lang.SystemClassLoaderAction.run(ClassLoader.java:2195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1456)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1436)
```

As seen on stackoverflow, I already tried different display options, like

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
setenv DISPLAY :0.0
unset DISPLAY
```

and some others, but unsuccessfully.
I suspect a GUI problem on my debian VM. An idea ?

Comment: As you can see in the stacktrace `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.processmining.framework.util.ProMClassLoader`there is a required class missing in the classpath

Comment: ok but I can run this script without error on my computer. Why doesn't it work on the VM ? Do you mean that the class is missing on the VM ?

Comment: It is missing in the classpath on your VM. Maybe it is in the classpath on your local machine